# WSO2 ESB Authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, wso2, esb

Is there a way to set up API requests authentication on the ESB server using configs or scripts (without java coding)? The authentication should be performed on the Identity Server (using external DB or LDAP or other). I'm planning to use http basic authentication.

Comment: basic authentication against incoming request for a service ? Can you explain bit more about your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAuth Mediator

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/OAuth+Mediator

Thanks